# Clearcase config spec behaves odd when using setcs command

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I have config spec stored in a text file . Following are the content

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element ...\lost+found\... -none
element \My\... MYF_R2.1.0.9.5179
element \My\... My_2.1.0.13.4875
element \My\... MyComponents_8_8_2011.6859
element \My\... My_2.1.0.13.7098
element \My\... My_2.1.0.13.8206
element \My\... My_2.1.0.13.433
element \My\... My_2.1.0.13.423
element \My\... My_2.1.0.13.3763
element \My\... My_2.1.0.13.5983
element \My\... My_2.1.0.13.7095
element \My\... My_2.1.0.13.5986
element \My\... My_2.1.0.13.8209
element \My\... My_2.1.0.13.437
element \My\... My_2.1.0.13.9321
element \My\... My_2.1.0.13.1548
element \My\... My_2.1.0.13.1537
element \My\... MyComponents_11_2_2011.461
element \My\... My_2.1.0.13.2649
element \My\... My_2.1.0.13.1534
element \My\... My_2.1.0.13.3760
element \My\... My_2.1.0.13.4872
element * /main/0
```

When i use cleartool setcs command upto "element \My... MyComponents_11_2_2011.461" line the config spec is updated and remaining lines were neglected.

While i added them manually , it works fine.

Any idea why setcs command behaves like that? is there any length restriction is there while using setcs command?

Following is my setcs command

```
cleartool setcs -tag $ViewName $ConfigSpec
```

Comment: We have cspecs with 300 lines in them...you've not reached the limit with 20 lines.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: I think you should be able to write a good book/posts  on practical applications of configuration management and help more people with your knowledge

Answer (score 2):

There is no special limitation, according to [`cleartool setcs` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setcs.htm).

The only way this file isn't applied completely while applied manually if is there is some kind of encoding issue or newline issue in that file.

A way to debug it is to:

- apply it manually
- `cleartool catcs -tag aViewTag > aFile`: see [`cleartool catcs` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_catcs.htm): redirect the content of a config spec for a given view in a file.
- compare `aFile` with your initial config spec file.