# how to find root[folder] for each component using cleartool?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, clearcase-ucm

How to find root folder in which a component is associated?

I am able to find it manually through project explorer -> Components-> properties

How to do it using cleartool command. I need it as i need to create config spec which can be applied in base clearcase view and view the UCM view contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look to the [options of "Format strings for command output" (fmt_ccase)](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm):

```
 cleartool descr -fmt "%[root_dir]p" component:aComponent@\aPVob
```

You can get that way to root directory (usually `\aVob` for "vob component" or "`\aVob\aRootDir`" for components within a Vob).

---

From there, for managing access to specific baselines of UCM components in *non-UCM* views, you can follow an approach similar to "[Merging from a Project to a Non-UCM Branch](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/rational/docs/v2003/cc_family/ccase/doc/all/cc_proj/parallel.htm)" in a perl script (done to merge, but you can adapt it, in order to build a config spec for said non-UCM view):

This script below is for projects which uses recommended baselines, and is given as an example of using the "`%[root_dir]p`".
If you don't use recommended baselines, you would simply list all components for a given stream:
`cleartool descr -fmt "%[components]CXp" stream:aStream@\aPVob`

```
print("######## Getting recommended baselines for project 
'$project'\n");
my @recbls = split(' ', ‘cleartool lsproject -fmt "%[rec_bls]p" 
$project‘);

foreach $bl (@recbls) {

    my $comp = ‘cleartool lsbl -fmt "%[component]p" $bl‘;
    my $vob = ‘cleartool lscomp -fmt "%[root_dir]p" $comp‘;

    #... build your config spec there
}
# call cleartool setsc there
```

You would then generate (and apply to a config spec) a file similar to your other question "[Clearcase config spec behaves odd when using `setcs` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604869/clearcase-config-spec-behaves-odd-when-using-setcs-command)".

---

The OP reports getting this approach working, using Powershell:
(he had initally issues with my example copied form the IBM site, where hyphens-minus '`-`' are replaced by non-ASCII minus '`–`': , '`- vs. –: -–`': see "[What's the toughest bug you ever found and fixed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169713/whats-the-toughest-bug-you-ever-found-and-fixed/170148#170148)"):

```
$project="MyComponents@\My_PVOB" 
$pvob="@\My_PVOB" 
$Baselines=(cleartool lsproject -fmt "%[rec_bls]p" $project).split() 
foreach ($bl in $Baselines) { 
  $comp=cleartool lsbl -fmt "%[component]p" $bl"$pvob" 
  $vob = cleartool lscomp -fmt "%[root_dir]p" $comp"$pvob" 
}
```

Comment: use strict;
my $project="Components@\My_PVOB";
my $bl;
print("######## Getting recommended baselines for project '$project'\n");
my @recbls = split(' ', `cleartool lsproject -fmt "%[rec_bls]p" $project`);
foreach $bl (@recbls) {
my $comp = `cleartool lsbl –fmt "%[component]p" $bl`;
my $vob = `cleartool lscomp –fmt "%[root_dir]p" $comp`;

    #... build your config spec there
}
# call cleartool setsc there
exit 0; " It fails as "cleartool: Error: Unable to determine VOB for pathname "My_PVOB"." I tried for 2 hours to solve but failed . What am i missing?

Comment: @Samselvaprabu First you need to know at what line it fails (`lsbl`? `lscomp`?). Then make sure (it never hurt to ask) that you have the right name/path for your PVob: `\MyPVob` for Windows, `/vobs/MyPVob` for Unix (and replace '`MyPVob`' by the name of your actual PVob of course). Finally, simplify. Make your script a one liner, trying to `lsbl` or `lscomp` just one object, and see if this works. Once you have debugged that, the rest of the initial and more complete script should work.

Comment: @Samselvaprabu: if you still have issues with some `cleartool` commands within that script, put the complete `cleartool` command and its complete output in those comments: I will debug them.

Comment: Thanks buddy .I think your contents are copied from some pdf or some other format. That is giving some utf format issues. Moreover PVOB name in windows requires @\PVob.                            "$project="MyComponents@\My_PVOB"
$pvob="@\My_PVOB"
$Baselines=(cleartool lsproject -fmt "%[rec_bls]p" $project).split()
foreach ($bl in $Baselines) {
    $comp=cleartool lsbl -fmt "%[component]p" $bl"$pvob"
    $vob = cleartool lscomp -fmt "%[root_dir]p" $comp"$pvob"
}" (I have used powershell )

Comment: Yes. Thanks buddy for going extra mile in your answer. ( Can you edit your answer? So that people who read your answer may not face format issue which i faced

Comment: @Samselvaprabu: Excellent. I have edited my answer to include your conclusions, and I have fixed all the minus signs, replacing it by hyphen-minus. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169713/whats-the-toughest-bug-you-ever-found-and-fixed/170148#170148