# CAL mkview command fails

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, cleartool

I am trying to create a clearcase view using COM object in Powershell.

```
$ccViews="\\Hostname.global.mycompany.com\cc-view\"
$ViewName="CodeCountView"
$ViewFullpath="$ccViews$ViewName"+".vws"

 $ct = new-object -com ClearCase.ClearTool

     try { 
         $ct.CmdExec('lsview $ViewName') 
     }
     catch {
         $ct.CmdExec('mkview -tag $ViewName -nsh $ViewFullpath')
      }
```

It throws following exception.

```
> Exception calling "CmdExec" with "1" argument(s): "storage directory
> must be in UNC style (e.g. \\host\share\...) " At
> E:\Powershellscripts\CCountAutomation.ps1:81 char:19
> +        $ct.CmdExec <<<< ('mkview -tag $ViewName -nsh $ViewFullpath')
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

Can some one help me to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change these lines:

```
$ct.CmdExec("lsview $ViewName") 

$ct.CmdExec("mkview -tag $ViewName -nsh $ViewFullpath")
```

Using `' $variable '` return the string $variable
Using `" $variable "` return the value asign to the variable.

Told this, in your code, you can also change this:

```
$ViewFullpath="$ccViews$ViewName.vws"
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to the (upvoted) Christian's answer, the technotes I found uses simple quotes: [swg1PK70509](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK70509)

```
$ct.CmdExec('lsact -fmt `'%[crm_state]p`'
```

But when using variable, double quotes are required, as illustrated in "[how to find root `[folder]` for each component using `cleartool`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8769988/6309)".