# How to update clearcase view via windows command line?

Tags: clearcase

I have a view named "Dev_view" in ClearCase and want to update the view via windows command line. Is there a way to do that?

In particular, what other command can trigger a view update?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [cleartool update](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_update.htm) command (for full ClearCase client, not for CCRC)

```
cd /path/of/your/snapshot/view
cleartool update .
```

You cal also add the following options:

```
-ove/rwrite
```

> Overwrites all hijacked files with the version selected by the config spec.

```
-nov/erwrite
```

> Leaves all hijacked files in the view with their current modifications.

```
-ren/ame/
```

> Renames hijacked files to filename.keep and copies the version in the VOB selected by the config spec into the view.

---

Note that updating the root directory of an UCM view have side-effect: it will re-evaluate the config spec of the view against its associate UCM stream, and will propose to update said config-spec (and proceed with the update).

This isn't the case for a non-UCM view, where a [`cleartool setcs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604869/clearcase-config-spec-behaves-odd-when-using-setcs-command/8604962#8604962) will always trigger the update after chaging the config spec.

Comment: excellent answer as always (I have stopped trying to respond to clearcase questions as you are always one up :). But this is an RTFM question. Should they be encouraged ?

Comment: @PulakAgrawal good point. I have added non-trivial information about this command in my edited answer.

Comment: Just so nobody else runs into this problem: if you have a recent version of cleartool, the slashes in the option switches are no longer used, just use `-overwrite` or `-rename` etc. Also, you have to put the option before the path, e.g. `cleartool update -overwrite .`.

Comment: @youR.Fate the '/' option? It is a shortcut: `cleartool update -ove` or `cleartool update -nov`. Is that shortcut not working with ClearCase 8.x (and rcleartool)?

Comment: Oh, I didn't interpret it as a shortcut, i tried `cleartool update -ove/rwrite .`. That didn't work. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @youR.Fate no problem. I confirm `cleartool update -ove/rwrite` wouldn't work, but `cleartool update -ove` should work.