# how to add view private files from sub directories to source control all at once from parent diectory

Tags: windows, clearcase

In my snapshot view. while working on source code through my IDE, I added lots of files at different sub directories. All those files become view-private files. 
I wanted to know is there any mechenism to get list of all view private files from parent directory?

I am new to clear case. I have used SVN mostly so my question is related to get all files at once and check, uncheck respective files in one dialog & add to source control, becomes easir for me.

Any command option will also do.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can see all files that are private:

See:

- "Find all files that are not added to ClearCase][1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2099195/6309)"
- "[How to find element(s) which are not present in the clearcase recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2099195/6309)"
- "[Command to find all view private files in the current directory recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7657120/6309)"

The main command is

```
# Windows
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %i in (`cleartool ls  -rec ^| find /V "Rule:" ^| find /V "hijacked" ^| find /V "eclipsed" ^| find /V "-->"`) do @echo "%i"

# Unix
cleartool ls -rec | grep -v "Rule:" | grep -v "hijacked" | grep -v "eclipsed" | grep -v "-->" | xargs echo
```

However, you need to know that **[ClearCase is file centric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645008/what-are-the-basic-clearcase-concepts-every-developer-should-know/645771#645771)**: it operates file by file.
Contrary to SVN, there is no neat dialog box for committing "all modified files" in one atomic fashion.

---

When you have a *lot of* private files to add, and you have them all over your snapshot view, one trick is:

- create a dynamic view (and mount the Vob in which you are working)
- set the same config spec than your snapshot view
- use the snapshot view as a source for a **[`clearfsimport` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/418196/6309)** to import the content of your snapshot view into your dynamic one.
  All identical elements won't be affected.
  Only new elements will be added to source control automatically, meaning the checkout of the parent directory, `mkelem` of the new element, and checkin of the parent directory will be done for you, automatically, for *all* new element during the import.
- [`cleartol update -overwrite`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12741082/6309) your snapshot view: the -overwrite option is important in order to transform your private file (which would be consider at this point as "hijacked" files) into official versioned elements.

(Note: the process is slightly different for an UCM view, but the idea remains: if you have a lot of new files to ad, `clearfsimport` is the tool for you).