# Issue with ucm development stream

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I have an integration stream with production baseline and several development streams as child streams. Now, when there are independent changes in different streams , it works fine. Now, there is a change in a file in stream A which is delievered to int stream. But, stream B is not aware of this and he makes his changes but when B is delivered to int stream, things dont work because B is not aware of the changes which were done by A and did not take that while writing his code. bOTH dev streams use hijacked files and snapshot view.

I see two solutions here but not sure if it really would work.
1. Merge changes from int to B as soon as A is delivered to int. Here, there could be issue when there is hijack file with changes in same lines.
2.Merge changes from all dev stream to B which does not look good as B may not need alll these changes.

Could you please advise how best to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would rebase `B` with a baseline from `int` (or, if inconvenient, deliver from `int` to `B`), in order to get all changes from `int` into `B`, and resolve potential conflict locally (in `B` UCM view)

Then, and only then, you put a new baseline on `B`, and deliver that to `int`.

Comment: This is what I had suggested as well but there seems to be an issue when developer working in B UCM snapshot view has his file hijacked for working locally and then how he needs to respond to this rebase with respect to this hijacked file.

Comment: @user2636464 He can do the rebase in a dedicated dynamic view (on stream B), and then update his current snapshot view (the update won't change its hijacked file)

Comment: the concern is if the update is on the same lines of code as the update being done in hijacked file and old changes get wiped out .

Comment: @user2636464 an update should preserve hijacked files. (unless you are using the `-overwrite` option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12741082/6309) Making a backup of the snapshot view remains a goof idea in any case.